# Line by line discord webhook formatting using python issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, webhooks

**Goal:** Have by webhook sorted line by line, rather than the info being next to each other.

**Current Status:**

```
Daily Mood Meter

Name: John Jones Date: 07/20 Outcome: Nice name
```

**As you can see, the info is all next to each other in the webhook, rather than how I would like it.** (view below)

**What I want:**

Daily Mood Meter

Name: John Jones

Date: 07/20

Outcome: Nice name

**What I currently have done:**

```
webhook = DiscordWebhook(webhook)

embed = DiscordEmbed(title="**Daily Mood Meter**", color=242424)

embed.set_footer(text="Created by Karma Automations")

embed.set_timestamp()

embed.add_embed_field(name="Name:",value=call)

embed.add_embed_field(name="Date:",value=date)

embed.add_embed_field(name="Outcome:",value=final)

webhook.add_embed(embed)

response = webhook.execute()
```

Comment: Yes, I can see that, good luck with fixing it! :)

Comment: How is this helpful?

Comment: You didn't ask a question or try to fix it yourself, at least your post doesn't make it seem that way. Maybe show us what you have already done to fix it and then we can help you. A request like "I want this"/"Do this for me" is out of place here. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Oh alright, I apologize. I am a new coder and new to stackoverflow, so I wasn't aware that was rude/out of place. I have been testing and trying methods, I'll make sure to mention that next time.

Comment: Are you aware of ways to have info stacked rather than side by side? By any chance?

Comment: It depends on your code. Can you show us what you have done?

Comment: Sure, let me edit the current post. Ok, edited. There is obviously more above but this is the code I used for the webhook. It sends good and everything, but the format isn't what I am looking for.

Comment: Just use `embed.add_embed_field(name="XXX:",value=call, inline=False/True)` - So use `True` or `False`, how you like it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Again, I apologize for before, I'm still new to all of this. Have a nice rest of your day!

Comment: No problem, have a good one and happy coding! :)